# How get POST request params in AuthorizationHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm implementing a Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core 2.2, but I can't access to POST request params in the Verification Handler.

I try doing something like this:

```cs
mvcContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["key"]
```

But when I access Request.Form give me this error:

```cs
'mvcContext.HttpContext.Request.Form' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

[image]
I try with GET params in Request.QueryString and work successfully.

What's the correct way of access to POST params? I missed some configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your screenshot, it seems you want to read key node from request json body, if so, you could try read body as json and then get the node value like

```
if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext mvcContext)
{
    var request = mvcContext.HttpContext.Request;
    request.EnableRewind();
    var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body);
    string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body, mvcContext.ActionDescriptor.Parameters.FirstOrDefault().ParameterType);
    JToken key;
    JObject.Parse(body).TryGetValue("key", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, out key);

    request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get body like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public string SampleMethod([FromBody] YourModel model)
{
    //access to the model here
}
```

If you want access to the context you should register IHttpContextAccessor in the start up class

```
services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```